Outline shader not loading in WebGl Build | Unity URP
I finished my web game. When I publish it and upload to itch.io or other game platforms, the outlines doesn't show up.
The game in the Unity editor:
enter image description here
The WebGl Build:
enter image description here
The shader is put on Universal Data: enter image description here
Here's my script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

public class ScreenSpaceOutlines : ScriptableRendererFeature {

    [System.Serializable]
    private class ScreenSpaceOutlineSettings {

        [Header("General Outline Settings")]
        public Color outlineColor = Color.black;
        [Range(0.0f, 20.0f)]
        public float outlineScale = 1.0f;
        
        [Header("Depth Settings")]
        [Range(0.0f, 100.0f)]
        public float depthThreshold = 1.5f;
        [Range(0.0f, 500.0f)]
        public float robertsCrossMultiplier = 100.0f;

        [Header("Normal Settings")]
        [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)]
        public float normalThreshold = 0.4f;

        [Header("Depth Normal Relation Settings")]
        [Range(0.0f, 2.0f)]
        public float steepAngleThreshold = 0.2f;
        [Range(0.0f, 500.0f)]
        public float steepAngleMultiplier = 25.0f;
        
        [Header("General Scene View Space Normal Texture Settings")]
        public RenderTextureFormat colorFormat;
        public int depthBufferBits;
        public FilterMode filterMode;
        public Color backgroundColor = Color.clear;

        [Header("View Space Normal Texture Object Draw Settings")]
        public PerObjectData perObjectData;
        public bool enableDynamicBatching;
        public bool enableInstancing;

    }

    private class ScreenSpaceOutlinePass : ScriptableRenderPass {
        
        private readonly Material screenSpaceOutlineMaterial;
        private ScreenSpaceOutlineSettings settings;

        private FilteringSettings filteringSettings;

        private readonly List<ShaderTagId> shaderTagIdList;
        private readonly Material normalsMaterial;

        private RTHandle normals;
        private RendererList normalsRenderersList;

        RTHandle temporaryBuffer;

        public ScreenSpaceOutlinePass(RenderPassEvent renderPassEvent, LayerMask layerMask,
            ScreenSpaceOutlineSettings settings) {
            this.settings = settings;
            this.renderPassEvent = renderPassEvent;

            screenSpaceOutlineMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/Outlines"));
            screenSpaceOutlineMaterial.SetColor("_OutlineColor", settings.outlineColor);
            screenSpaceOutlineMaterial.SetFloat("_OutlineScale", settings.outlineScale);

            screenSpaceOutlineMaterial.SetFloat("_DepthThreshold", settings.depthThreshold);
            screenSpaceOutlineMaterial.SetFloat("_RobertsCrossMultiplier", settings.robertsCrossMultiplier);

            screenSpaceOutlineMaterial.SetFloat("_NormalThreshold", settings.normalThreshold);

            screenSpaceOutlineMaterial.SetFloat("_SteepAngleThreshold", settings.steepAngleThreshold);
            screenSpaceOutlineMaterial.SetFloat("_SteepAngleMultiplier", settings.steepAngleMultiplier);
            
            filteringSettings = new FilteringSettings(RenderQueueRange.opaque, layerMask);

            shaderTagIdList = new List<ShaderTagId> {
                new ShaderTagId("UniversalForward"),
                new ShaderTagId("UniversalForwardOnly"),
                new ShaderTagId("LightweightForward"),
                new ShaderTagId("SRPDefaultUnlit")
            };

            normalsMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/ViewSpaceNormals"));
        }

        public override void OnCameraSetup(CommandBuffer cmd, ref RenderingData renderingData) {
            // Normals
            RenderTextureDescriptor textureDescriptor = renderingData.cameraData.cameraTargetDescriptor;
            textureDescriptor.colorFormat = settings.colorFormat;
            textureDescriptor.depthBufferBits = settings.depthBufferBits;
            RenderingUtils.ReAllocateIfNeeded(ref normals, textureDescriptor, settings.filterMode);
            
            // Color Buffer
            textureDescriptor.depthBufferBits = 0;
            RenderingUtils.ReAllocateIfNeeded(ref temporaryBuffer, textureDescriptor, FilterMode.Bilinear);

            ConfigureTarget(normals, renderingData.cameraData.renderer.cameraDepthTargetHandle);
            ConfigureClear(ClearFlag.Color, settings.backgroundColor);
        }

        public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData) {
            if (!screenSpaceOutlineMaterial || !normalsMaterial || 
                renderingData.cameraData.renderer.cameraColorTargetHandle.rt == null || temporaryBuffer.rt == null)
                return;

            CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get();
            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
            cmd.Clear();
                
            // Normals
            DrawingSettings drawSettings = CreateDrawingSettings(shaderTagIdList, ref renderingData, renderingData.cameraData.defaultOpaqueSortFlags);
            drawSettings.perObjectData = settings.perObjectData;
            drawSettings.enableDynamicBatching = settings.enableDynamicBatching;
            drawSettings.enableInstancing = settings.enableInstancing;
            drawSettings.overrideMaterial = normalsMaterial;
            
            RendererListParams normalsRenderersParams = new RendererListParams(renderingData.cullResults, drawSettings, filteringSettings);
            normalsRenderersList = context.CreateRendererList(ref normalsRenderersParams);
            cmd.DrawRendererList(normalsRenderersList);
            
            // Pass in RT for Outlines shader
            cmd.SetGlobalTexture(Shader.PropertyToID("_SceneViewSpaceNormals"), normals.rt);
            
            using (new ProfilingScope(cmd, new ProfilingSampler("ScreenSpaceOutlines"))) {

                Blitter.BlitCameraTexture(cmd, renderingData.cameraData.renderer.cameraColorTargetHandle, temporaryBuffer, screenSpaceOutlineMaterial, 0);
                Blitter.BlitCameraTexture(cmd, temporaryBuffer, renderingData.cameraData.renderer.cameraColorTargetHandle);
            }

            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
            CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
        }

        public void Release(){
            CoreUtils.Destroy(screenSpaceOutlineMaterial);
            CoreUtils.Destroy(normalsMaterial);
            normals?.Release();
            temporaryBuffer?.Release();
        }

    }

    [SerializeField] private RenderPassEvent renderPassEvent = RenderPassEvent.BeforeRenderingSkybox;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask outlinesLayerMask;
    
    [SerializeField] private ScreenSpaceOutlineSettings outlineSettings = new ScreenSpaceOutlineSettings();

    private ScreenSpaceOutlinePass screenSpaceOutlinePass;
    
    public override void Create() {
        if (renderPassEvent < RenderPassEvent.BeforeRenderingPrePasses)
            renderPassEvent = RenderPassEvent.BeforeRenderingPrePasses;

        screenSpaceOutlinePass = new ScreenSpaceOutlinePass(renderPassEvent, outlinesLayerMask, outlineSettings);
    }

    public override void AddRenderPasses(ScriptableRenderer renderer, ref RenderingData renderingData) {
        renderer.EnqueuePass(screenSpaceOutlinePass);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing){
        if (disposing)
        {
            screenSpaceOutlinePass?.Release();
        }
    }

}


I tried to create a new project and import the outline shader there to check If there is something wrong with my game. It still doesn't load the shaders.
I'm currently using Unity 2022.3.15f1
Is this a bug or do I have to do something?

do you get any webgl errors when running?

Show us your shaders.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Bart changed the post. I added the script of the Outline's shader.

@BugFinder if It's on console then nope.

thats a script, not a shader :p but, pink usually means, missing or invalid material/shader

@BugFinder the outline shader is supposed to be pink and do I show the shader graph? :)
